# Grafana query for time delta

Tags: java, grafana, prometheus

I have an app which, among other things, continuously publishes current time in milliseconds since epoch (System.currentTimeMillis()).

What I want to do is write a query in grafana dashboard such that:
a) It shows "Up" if the difference between current time in grafana & my published time is less than 1 min.
b) Shows "Down" is the above query doesn't hold or there is no data.

Any ideas, pointers will be most helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could pass the value of your real timestamp to grafana, as a "long" or "timestamp" field , named `real_ts` (maybe there's another way, sorry, not expert in grafana).

Then, substract grafana's timestamp with your `real_ts` field's value, and if >60 seconds, print Down, if not, print Up.